# Start chat with contact or open People profile from my app

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In my Windows 8 Store app the user can pick a contact via the [`ContactPicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR224913). I then want to be able to use the information to start chat with/send a single instant message to that contact. However, for all the contacts I pick on my machine, the [`InstantMessages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactinformation.instantmessages%28v=win.10%29.aspx) property is empty ([`CustomFields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactinformation.customfields.aspx) as well). All of my contacts come from Skype or Messenger, and when I open the People app they all have the option to send an instant message.
The code I have tried:

```
var contactPicker = new ContactPicker();
contactPicker.SelectionMode = ContactSelectionMode.Contacts;
var contacts = await contactPicker.PickMultipleContactsAsync();
ContactInformation contact = null;
foreach (var c in contacts) {
    if (c.InstantMessages.Count > 0) {
        contact = c;
        break;
    }
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464950.aspx):

> You can let your users access their contacts so they can share content, email, or **messages with each other**, or whatever functionality you design.

But there is only a tutorial/sample on how to pick contacts info. Am I missing something?
Opening the user profile in the People app works as well.

**Edit**:
I should probably clarify that by "start chat with/send a single instant message to that contact" I mean to trigger an existing app (e.g. by using some URI). Like Skype for contacts that have Skype listed on their profile.

Comment: It is interesting to note that even if I have facebook contacts - no contact seem to come with instanceMessages info. It is likely unsupported by the API. but someone from msft should confirm.